# javascript: http-response into frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

I have a programm in React that

does a http-request during componentWillMount and sets a variable
response on the response of the http-request

```
var response = "";
class App extends Component{
  componentWillMount(){
     var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = 'GET',
        url = //url; 
      myRequest.open(method, url, true);
      myRequest.send();
      myRequest.onload = function() {
        response = myRequest.response;
    };
```

and that displays the response in the method render() by using the "response" variable.

However, this is not working -> the initial value "" is displayed. The HTTP-Request is working (tested), the HTTP-Response is recieved and correct(also tested), so perhaps the program is just not waiting untill the http request is done and instead takes the initial value for "response".

How can i fix this, i.e. how can i enforce that response is set to the HTTP-response?

Comment: I think you may want to make `response` into a state. Then initially the `response` state will be "", but then when `response` state got overwrite, it will trigger re-render to get you the latest value

Comment: Thank you :) do i use the build-in state in the constructor of the component for this? sorry... quite new to web development

Comment: I’d recommend a tutorial.

Comment: I recommend this react tutorial: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn

Comment: you [really shouldn't](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) be using `componentWillMount`. Also there's no reason in a React app to use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of the modern `fetch`.

Comment: As for why your component isn't updating - it won't rerender on a change of the `response` variable because that's not in component props or state. You probably want to use state for this.